# Process Add XMLA measure group SSIS

Tags: ssis, ssas, ssis-2012, xmla

Is it possible to execute process add on measure cube in SSIS? I tried to look for the XMLA script but I don't see anything for it. I need to run the script several times with different where parameter (Add processing will need to be added to for loop container)

Answer (score 1):

The [Analysis Services Processing Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/analysis-services-processing-task?view=sql-server-ver15) allows you to process Analysis services cubes, and it should allow you to specify Process Add in the [processing options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/multidimensional-models/processing-options-and-settings-analysis-services?view=asallproducts-allversions#processing-settings).

If that doesn't work for your scenario, there is also the [Analysis Services Execute DDL Task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/analysis-services-execute-ddl-task?view=sql-server-ver15) which allows you to execute raw XMLA commands, so you could construct and execute the XMLA to do the processing you require.